# Identical paths render to different sizes when their colors are inverted?

Tags: .net, gdi+

Well im rendering the same path 2 times one time with a white brush on a black background and one with a black brush on a white background.

Now the result should be the same image but inverted right?

Well wrong the one that's drawn on the black background is a few pixels bigger..

[image]
[image]

Diff

[image]

Code i used to draw these

```
PointF[] points = LoadXml<PointF[]>(@"T:\Points.xml");
byte[] types = LoadXml<byte[]>(@"T:\Types.xml");
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath(points, types, FillMode.Alternate);
using (Image image = new Bitmap(45, 45))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        Render(g, Color.White, Color.Black, path);
    }
    image.Save(@"T:\White.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
using (Image image = new Bitmap(45, 45))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        Render(g, Color.Black, Color.White, path);
    }
    image.Save(@"T:\Black.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
}

private static T LoadXml<T>(string file)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}

private static void Render(Graphics g, Color mainColor, Color backColor, GraphicsPath graphicsPath)
{
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;

    g.Clear(backColor);
    using (SolidBrush mainBrush = new SolidBrush(mainColor))
    {
        g.FillPath(mainBrush, graphicsPath);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make them render the same way without modifying the path?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just an optical illusion? The look the same to me.

Comment: look at the space between the squares its different I have even used a compare tool to verify it. added one more image that shows this diff.

Comment: Turn off the filter and post the images

Comment: It's most likely your anti-aliasing.  The pixels need to steal from their neighbors in order to make the drawing look smooth.  The white and black are attacking the drawing differently.  Try commenting out those first four lines in your `Render` method.

Comment: @Petoj I said filter, and meant the bi-linear interpolation mode. Ie bi-linear filter. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @LarsTech thanks its seems it was CompositingQuality!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atmittedly, I am just guessing, but:

It could be the result of GDI+ attempting to do gamma-correct rendering. (I didn't check that it does).

Historically, display monitors are non-linear. So a pixel with a grayscale value of 255 is much more than twice as bright as a pixel with value 128. So, if you are trying to anti-alias a line, and want a draw a pixel that is 50% covered with white, a pixel with value 128 is too dark. It is more like 25% white. To get a 50% white pixel, you should take a value around 180 (I don't remember exactly).

This would cause the white image to be half a pixel larger than the black one, if you compare it to the inverse.

Comment: For the record, CompositingQuality controls gamma correction, so this answer turned out to be correct.